# How can show all permission to user for acceptation at one time in marshmallow?

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

i have 10 permission in my app and i am able to prompt one by one. but i want 10 permission once prompt to the user so that he can accept permission on app start.

Thanks in advance

Comment: if you are talking about all dangerous permissions, it would be in the form of 10 dialogs of "allow" or "deny" which can appear as "1 of 10", "2 of 10"...written aligned left in the row of allow and deny

Comment: The whole point of the runtime permissions is that users do not need to grant them until your app actually needs them. Just lower your targetSdk to 22 if you don't want to do that.

Comment: I want access four permission Contact,Location,Gallery ,Accounts

Comment: never tried it, but look at this post: http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en

Comment: Also you should remember, that user can revoke permission at any time. So even if your application is granted this permission at launch time, then there is no guarantee that they will be sill granted at the moment you will for example try to take photo or write some file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ask multiple permissions together in this manner:
(I currently use it like this)

```
 String[] PERMISSIONS_ARRAY = {Manifest.permission.X, Manifest.permission.Y, Manifest.permission.Z};
```

Then i have a function:

```
void checkRuntimePermissions(){
        if ((ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.X)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission ...) {  

 //modify the array acc to permission granted or not

 if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.X) && ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale...{  

ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Activity.this, PERMISSIONS_ARRAY,
                            REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS);
} ..}
```

And verify the requests with implementing [ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback.html)...

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS) {
            // if we have requested multiple permissions, all of them need to be
            // checked.
            if (PermissionUtil.verifyPermissions(grantResults)) {...
```

I hope we get an automatic check from the o.s. when calling `requestPermissions...` so we do not have to check if the permission is allowed.

[google samples code for reference](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-RuntimePermissions)

Answer (score 1):

`requestPermissions` takes an array of strings as first argument, so...

```
requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.X, Manifest.permission.Y}, requestCode);
```

But...

The whole point of the runtime permissions is that users do not need to grant them until your app actually needs them.

Answer (score -1):

I have created a runtime permission helper which exactly does what you want.
You can find it here - https://gist.github.com/passiondroid/cd2ad32e7ba26f4e47ae

After adding this class and modifying according to your permissions. You can add below code in  your activity where you need to ask all the permissions

```
runtimePermissionHelper = RuntimePermissionHelper.getInstance(this);
            if (runtimePermissionHelper.isAllMCPermissionAvailable()) {
                //All permissions available. Do what you want.
            } else {
                runtimePermissionHelper.setActivity(this);
                runtimePermissionHelper.requestPermissionsIfDenied();
            }
```

Override this method in the same activity to get callback once user accepts/rejects permissions

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    Map<String, Integer> perms = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    // Fill with results*/
    for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++)
        perms.put(permissions[i], grantResults[i]);

    boolean isAllPermissionsAllowed = false;
    for(int i : grantResults){
        if(i==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            isAllPermissionsAllowed = true;
        }else{
            isAllPermissionsAllowed = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(isAllPermissionsAllowed){
        //All permissions available. Do what you want.
    } else {
        // Permission Denied. Show error page
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,ErrorActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("permissions_denied",true);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```